# What does "stocked" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

What does this sentence mean "I make sure everything stays clean and stocked"? 
I don't understand the word "stocked". Please explain to me! Thank you so much!

Comment: The sentence is wrong, or a typo. Should be possibly "clean and stacked".  however that does not really make sense - you'd mean "Clean and tidily-stacked" or "clean and nicely stacked" or "clean and stacked in an orderly fashion."  It could mean "stocked" (explained below) but again the sentence is not really right.

Comment: A larger context might be helpful. The words *clean* and *stocked* do not offer enough information in this sentence to determine a clear meaning decisively.

Comment: I read it on page "Humans of New York" and I really don't know what it means. "I work in the Pots and Plants Department. I make sure everything stays clean and stocked and I help people can find what they’re looking for". Maybe it can help clearly. I'm sorry about my grammar!

Comment: Hi @HườngNguyễn, welcome to ELU. It helps us to help you if you edit and put the context (the sentence or two before your main sentence in the question itself. Also, look up the word in the dictionary and tell us if none of its definitions work for you (then it might be reopened).

Answer (score 3):

As a verb, *[stock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stock)* means

> Have or keep a supply of (a particular product or type or product) available for sale:
>   *most supermarkets now stock a range of organic produce*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Someone working in a store may be responsible for keeping the premises clean and the supply of goods on shelves adequate.

Comment: true of course but ":clean and stocked" really does not work very well.

Comment: @JoeBlow It might well refer to a pond intended for casual fishing. I agree it sounds a bit clumsy. *Clean and well stocked would sound better. But again, it needs context.

Comment: LOL - brilliant on the pond.  I believe "everything stays clean and stocked" can't be correctly formulated. Clean can only refer to extant physical (real, touchable) items and "stocked" can only refer to (abstract, conceptual) product lines. You can't shove 'em together, really, without a bit more fluff in there.  Thus, you can say that a **shop**, say, or the **wine section**, must remain stocked; there's no similar category that "everything stays clean" can refer to.  Of course, it doesn't matter all that much :)

Comment: @Joe B;ow: perhaps the OP can offer more context yp confirm, but this is the likely usage. e/g. "I work at Trader Koe's. I make sure everything is clean and stocked. "

Comment: @JoeBlow I think you are being too harsh without knowing a lot more about the situation. It sounds perfectly natural in the grocery store situation.